# pjax titles not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

Pjax titles aren't working in my Rails 3.2.3 app. Everything else works fine.

Here's the title tag in my application.html.haml:

```
%title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : SITE_NAME
```

I've verified that there is indeed `content_for(:title)` by rendering it in the partial that pjax loads (and it works fine if the whole page is reloaded). Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a page is request by pjax it is rendered without a layout, so anything done in application.html.haml is irrelevant.

You need to include the  tag in the HTML that gets rendered. Pjax will remove it from the page (since clearly title tags don't belong in the body) and use it to set the page title.

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I thought there was some exception for the title tag.

Comment: Incredible useful answer that is not document anywhere (Like Really?) but is totally completely correct and awesome. Thanks Much!

Answer (score 0):

Since [#57](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/pull/57) pjax also looks for a data attribute `data-title` in the fragment that is loaded and should update the main title.

This is much cleaner and would not break `html` with a `title` in the `body`.